# 1048, "Column 'last_name' cannot be null" Django AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-auth-models

I'm trying to create a registration for each new account using the `UserCreationForm` from the form to `CreateView` class-base view generics from views, from my customize auth model using `AbstractUser` but everytime submit the form it gives me this error:

```
1048, "Column 'last_name' cannot be null"
```

But I already fill in the last_name `input`

here is my views for creating account:

```
class AccountCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'components/crud/form.html'
    form_class    = AccountForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context_title']        = 'New Account'
        kwargs['context_icon']         = '<em class="fa fa-plus"></em>'
        kwargs['context_button_title'] = 'Create Account'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(self.request.POST.get('last_name'))
        try:
            self.object = form.save()
            messages.success(self.request, '<em class="fa fa-check"></em> Account created!')
        except IntegrityError as e:
            messages.error(self.request, f'<em class="fa fa-exclamation"></em> {e}')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('apps:newaccount')
```

Here is the form:

```
class AccountForm(UserCreationForm):

    def clean_first_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        if data == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('What\'s your name?'))
        return data

    def clean_last_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        if data == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('What\'s your last name?'))

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if data == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('What\'s was the email address for this account?'))
        return data

    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if data == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Provide your username.'))
        return data

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.pop('autofocus', None)
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({
            'autofocus': True
        })
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = False
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model  = Users
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_type', ) + UserCreationForm.Meta.fields
```

Note that I already put `AUTH_USER_MODEL` on the settings by
and I can use to login some accounts already register in the auth model generated by this:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning data from `clean_last_name` hence error

```
def clean_last_name(self):
    ....
    return data
```

Comment: the fudge! yeah I forgot! it is only just because of this I already got confuse, I never look at my code carefully! oh well thanks a lot!